# Book Title Meaning

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, punctuation, ambiguity

So if a book's title is "I love you,Nora Jane"

What does it mean? Does it mean that Nora Jane is saying she loves him or the boy is saying he loves her.What about the ','(comma) that comes. Doesn't it mean Nora Jane is saying it or can we just say the boy meant her name.

(P.s the book till now is written from boy's perspective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's in the form of quoted speech, we don't know who "I" is. However, with the comma before it "Nora Jane" is most likely a form of address, meaning whoever is speaking is speaking *to* Nora Jane. (There's a vague possibility it's intended to be a signature, but that would be pretty ambiguous.)

In other words, assuming the most likely scenario (that the speaker is addressing Nora Jane), we don't know who is doing the loving, but Nora Jane is the one who is being loved. The person who loves Nora Jane could be her mother, brother, lover, or friend. Since you say it's written from a "boy's" perspective, he's probably supposed to be the one doing the talking (and the one who loves Nora Jane).

You can read more examples of direct address here: https://www.thoughtco.com/direct-address-grammar-and-rhetoric-1690457

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The image of the "front cover" of this work of fanfiction is ambiguous; and it may be on purpose. The title could be either a note *from* Nora Jane, or it could be a note *to* Nora Jane; it could mean both. That is why literature, even the title of a story, is ambiguous. When it's ambiguous, or possibly ambiguous, it's up to the reader to decide, or at least wonder. In art, there is no right or wrong answer or interpretation.

Comment: But by the fact that this Fan fiction is written by the boy's perspective.. Its better to interpretate that he's the one talking to Nora Jane

Comment: @ClaylaJohn That's one interpretation. Whether it's better or not is up to each individual reader.